# organic hard surf wax?

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, water, solutions

I made some organic surf wax with 4 parts beeswax and 1 part coconut oil. The wax turned out to be sticky but had no tack.

I'd like to make wax for warm water that forms a layer of hard bumps on the board when wax is applied.

Not sure how I can achieve this w all organic items.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

[Carnauba wax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnauba_wax) is a high-melting wax that should be suitable. In the Wikipedia article cited,
"Carnauba wax can produce a glossy finish... It was commonly used in its purest form as a coating on speedboat hulls in the early 1960s to enhance speed and aid in handling in salt water environments. **It is also the main ingredient in surfboard wax**, combined with coconut oil."